# Is it possible to catch an object with the node.error() function on Node-RED?

Tags: node-red

Let's say I have the following flow:

[image]

The function node called `error that we can catch but catch node doesn't see objects` has the code:

```js
const object = {
   "key1": "value1", 
   "key2": "value2"
}
node.error(object, msg)
```

If I run it the error will be caught by the `catch node` as follows:

[image]

Even though it catches the error, it only accepts strings and not objects when using `node.error(object, msg)`. It'd work fine if not using the catch node... But when I use it I'll always receive `[Object Object]` in the catch node...

---

The node `error that we cannot catch` has the code:

```js
const object = {
   "key1": "value1", 
   "key2": "value2"
}
msg.error = object

node.error(msg)
```

This node on the other hand prints the messages to the debug window but its messages are never caught by the `catch node`.

I'd like to make it in a way that I'll use the `catch node` to catch objects that I send as errors on my flow. Is it possible to do? Or the `catch node` doesn't support catching objects?

samples:

```json
[{"id":"8bdb7d23cef69c8f","type":"catch","z":"e31af9f309041c23","name":"","scope":["31ef17186604a4ff","ac478768a62912b0"],"uncaught":false,"x":1390,"y":760,"wires":[["0dce50f2ce849b21"]]},{"id":"0dce50f2ce849b21","type":"debug","z":"e31af9f309041c23","name":"debug 1","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","targetType":"full","statusVal":"","statusType":"auto","x":1580,"y":760,"wires":[]},{"id":"31ef17186604a4ff","type":"function","z":"e31af9f309041c23","name":"error that we can catch but catch node doesn't see objects","currentLine":{"row":0,"column":0},"func":"const object = {\n   \"key1\": \"value1\", \n   \"key2\": \"value2\"\n}\nnode.error(object, msg)","outputs":0,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","libs":[],"x":1730,"y":620,"wires":[]},{"id":"38ec456b9cfe72ae","type":"inject","z":"e31af9f309041c23","name":"","props":[{"p":"payload"},{"p":"topic","vt":"str"}],"repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","x":1420,"y":620,"wires":[["31ef17186604a4ff"]]},{"id":"ac478768a62912b0","type":"function","z":"e31af9f309041c23","name":"error that we cannot catch","currentLine":{"row":0,"column":0},"func":"const object = {\n   \"key1\": \"value1\", \n   \"key2\": \"value2\"\n}\nmsg.error = object\n\nnode.error(msg)","outputs":0,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","libs":[],"x":1630,"y":680,"wires":[]},{"id":"2c5f9396a10118b3","type":"inject","z":"e31af9f309041c23","name":"","props":[{"p":"payload"},{"p":"topic","vt":"str"}],"repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","x":1420,"y":680,"wires":[["ac478768a62912b0"]]}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `node.error()` should be a string, not an object. This is because it is explicitly meant to be a human readable **message**.

Just do what you have done in the second instance, but include a text message to go with the error:

```
const object = {
   "key1": "value1", 
   "key2": "value2"
}
msg.error = object

node.error("Some error message",msg)
```